# UML message logic

Tags: uml

The pictures below shows a sequences of messages
They represent the following situations :

- Synchronous message NOT immediately followed by its response (pic 1)
- A (stimuli) message be launch right after a reesponse by the same object (pic 1)
- Can a self message be triggered without a stimuli (pic 2)

My question is : as long as these respresent the logic inside the case description it is OK right ?  Or does UML imposes some sort of logic to follow for the way message (stimuli) and their responses (return) mustbe sequenced ?

**Pic 1**

[image]

**Pic 2**

[image]

**EDITED PICTURES**

**Pic 1**

[image]

**Pic 2**

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Yes, UML does have rules. Why don't you download the UML 2.5 spec and read the section on sequence diagrams? It tells you all the rules. See http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF .

Comment: Probably out of the same reason, most people don't do: it's not a user manual but rather a vendor's guide. But the question stands: why do you want to model a self-call "out of thin air"? Of course, the other message also start from "nowhere", but there's a use case behind which explains the first message in a sequence.

Comment: @JimL. Downloaded it. I'll skimm to see if I find something.  And I have added more details to the picture so it makes more sense

Comment: @ThomasKilian  Not out of thin air. I have added more details to the picture so it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that both have flaws since you use asynchronous messages for the self-messages. While that might be valid, it's most likely a wrong use here. Send an asynchronous message to self means what? A message in a bottle that will be found later? Some fork-message? Now assuming you meant a synchronous message, you probably want to extent the life line from above since the Check Name Length will likely be a sequential action somewhen after the user name is received.

**wrt edit pict 1** If that is you intention, it is fine. However, I once again doubt that. It is called Check Name Length, and unless you are doing that for pure fun, you will likely somewhere deal with the result of the check. And if this is asynchronous, then how will you know if the check is complete?

Comment: I edited as you said. But I kept asynchronous self message in the first diagram ; from what I understand, the asynchronous does not require a response. I don't need one in the first diagram

Comment: See my addition in the answer.